# Allocating students to colleges based on their marks

Tags: sql, algorithm

I know I might be stoned for this question, and it might be labeled off-topic, but I am desperate for help.

I need to create a system to allocate students to colleges based on their marks. And I need to know what kind of algorithm to use. I am not good with algorithms.

I have the following tables:

College:

```
id | name | capacity
--------------------
1  | C1   | 50
2  | C2   | 30
```

Student:

```
id | name | degree | status
----------------------------
1  | S1   | 90     | 0
2  | S2   | 77     | 0
```

Student selection:

```
student_id | college_id | choice_order
---------------------------------------
1          | 10         | 1
1          | 3          | 2
```

So basically what I need is to allocate students to the correct college based on their selection sequence, and marks, and of course based on college capacity. So we first pick the top 50 students with choice_order 1 to be allocated to the first college. Those who didn't make it, should be allocated to their second choice, etc..

My basic query would be something like this for college 1:

```
SELECT * FROM student 
INNER JOIN student_selection ON student.id = student_selection.student_id
WHERE college_id = 1 AND choice_order = 1 AND status = 0 
Limit 50;
```

Those selected students will be allocated to college 1, and removed from algorithm:
`UPDATE student SET status = 1 WHERE ...`

Yet I know this is not going to work, since I need some sort of recursive algorithm that when a student fails to get the college in sequence 1 due to low mark, we need to check his second choice, etc..

Any lead or tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your approach, you risk filling up college 1 with E students, leaving no seats for A students that have college 1 as second choice. I'd work my way down the list of students, ordered by grade (descending), making sure each one has a seat before moving on to the next.

Comment: That's why I need some recursive option, which re-process the whole thing to make sure everyone got a fair chance.

Answer (score 1):

> I need some sort of recursive algorithm

not recursive you need simple loop. As you are talking about algorithm and do not say something about programming language i show some "pseudocode" (it can be Delphi, C++, C#.. and also PSQL, T-SQL..)
But to simplify i have changed your table definition

Also this is not full answer (some pseudocode to direction) - as stackoverflow is not for writing the code for you only solve issues.

College:

```
id | name | capacity | remained |
---------------------------------
1  | C1   | 50       | 50       | 
2  | C2   | 30       | 30       |
```

Student:

```
id | name | degree | college_id
-------------------------------
1  | S1   | 90     | null
2  | S2   | 77     | null
```

Student selection:

```
student_id | college_id | choice_order
---------------------------------------
1          | 10         | 1
1          | 3          | 2
```

_

```
Var choice: Integer;
Var WasSelection: Boolean;

WasSelection:= true;
while WasSelection do
    begin
        WasSelection:= false;
        while not College.Eof do
            begin
                choice:= 0;
                while true do
                    begin
                        choice:= choice + 1;

                        SELECT * FROM student 
                        INNER JOIN student_selection ON student.id = student_selection.student_id
                        WHERE college_id = :College.id AND choice_order = :choice AND college_id is null 
                        Limit :College.remained;

                        if ABOVE_SELECT_RECORD_COUNT=0 then
                          break; //!!! end loop 

                        WasSelection:= true;
                        UPDATE student SET college_id = :College.id WHERE ...  
                        UPDATE College SET remained = remained - :ABOVE_SELECT_RECORD_COUNT  WHERE college_id = :College.id  
                    end
                College.Next;
            end
    end
```

**UPDATE after comment**
your comment change things as priority is grade and selection.

```
SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY GRADE

while not student.eof do
    begin
        select TOP 1 * from student_selection S INNER JOIN College C on S.college_id = C.ID WHERE student_selection.student_id= :student.id AND C.remained>0 ORDER BY choice_order

        if ABOVE_SELECT_RECORD_COUNT>0 then
            begin
                UPDATE student SET college_id = :College.id WHERE student.id= :student.id;  
                UPDATE College SET remained = remained - 1 WHERE college_id = :student_selection.college_id; 
            end

        student.next;
    end
```

as in my comment
You need also consider what to do if you have 2 studends with same grade and also what if student do not got any college but others college have remaining places but are not on student selection list

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am more than fine with psudo code. I will consider your logic, even though it's not enough. If student 1 ended up not accepted for choice 1, he needs to be competing for his choice 2, which might end up rejecting an already accepted student 3 in case  student 1 had better mark than student 3.

Comment: If you need consider grade then approach should be different. Do not go throught college only by students ordering by grade. You need also consider what to do if you have 2 studends with same grade and also what if student do not got any college but others college have remaining places but are not on student selection list

Answer (score 0):

From your question (emphasis mine):

> So we first pick the top 50 students with choice_order 1 to be allocated to the **first college**.

From your comment on Livius's answer (again, emphasis mine):

> If student 1 ended up not accepted for choice 1, he needs to be competing for his choice 2, which might end up **rejecting an already accepted student 3** in case student 1 had better mark than student 3.

I think you are making things needlessly complex. If a student's grade trumps another student's preference, then follow up on that in your algorithm. Instead of starting with the first college, start with the highest-rated student. By deciding on a student's assignment *before* assigning any lower-rated students, you will never have to unassign a student later on.

I'd propose the following algorithm:

1. Get the top 1 student (i.e. highest marks) that has not been assigned yet.
2. Get the top 1 college (when ordered by this student's preference) where remaining capacity > 0.
3. Assign the student to the college.
4. Decrease remaining capacity of the college.
5. Repeat from step 1 until everyone has been assigned, or all capacity has been consumed.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if I missed any important requirements that warrant a more complex approach.